# No response during earlier part of this week

Tags: internship, email, manager, hiring

I have been offered an internship position in the Group after which I had cold-mailed the Engineering Lead regarding a suitable profile. He cc'ed the mail to another lead(say X) who is working with hiring managers to see if a team would be interested in me. X has told me that I should be expecting an email early this week, but it is Wednesday and there is no response yet. In my earlier mail, I had attached my CV and expressed my passion in the field of this group.

Comment: I would say give it the rest of the week.  If you haven't heard back by the end of the week, you could probably send a follow up email.  They could have just gotten busy and they didn't have time to get back to you.

Comment: Thanks @New-To-IT. What should I exactly be telling him during the end of week? I want to be as polite as possible and have absolutely no intentions to irritate him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait until Thursday or Friday to follow up on the status of your internship placement.

> Hi X,
>
> I hope you are doing well. I am very excited about an internship at Company. Could you tell me the current status of my internship placement ?
>
> Thank you,
>
> envy_intelligence

Comment: Thank you @jcmack. I have been offered the job. The recruiter told me that it is a general offer and exact placement within the group will take a while. Meanwhile, I have started mailing my resume to managers through other contacts.

Comment: @envy_intelligence Good information I have edited the wording in my answer. I have heard of this type of situation before. Still waiting until tomorrow or Friday is fine.